# Bracketed if inside non bracketed foreach

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, foreach

This may have been answered somewhere before but I could not figure out a good way to word my search.

```
foreach(item in list)
  if(something)
  {
    dosomething();
  }
if(somethingunrelated)
  {
    dosomethingunrelated();
  }
```

Besides the obvious of being extremely hard to read, is there any way that either if statement might be skipped?

What I think is expected here is that the foreach will iterate over every item in the list and apply the first if statement. After the foreach is completed the second if will be applied once.

I did not write this and am scouring to find an issue on a legacy system. I don't *think* this is it, but I seem to remember that you can ONLY skip brackets if everything nested skips the brackets as well (in c#.net). Is that correct?

Comment: *What I think is expected here is that the foreach will iterate over every item in the list and apply the first if statement. After the foreach is completed the second if will be applied once.* You are correct.

Comment: No you remember wrong

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Second `if` will only be hit one time, after the `foreach` has finished executing.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad Can't run the code, can't create new code right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach(item in list)
    if(something)
    {
        dosomething();
    }
    if(somethingunrelated)
    {
        dosomethingunrelated();
    }
```

is logically the same as this

```
foreach(item in list)
{
    if(something)
    {
        dosomething();
    }
}
if(somethingunrelated)
{
    dosomethingunrelated();
}
```

don't be fooled by indentation.

Answer (score 3):

> I seem to remember that you can ONLY skip brackets if everything nested skips the brackets as well

No - if you omit brackets then *only the next single statement* will be in the scope.  The "single statement" can be a bracketed statement, so in your case

```
foreach(...)
    if   <--
    {      |
           | // will  get executed for each item
    }    <--
if   
{  
    // will get executed after the `foreach` is complete.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Second `if` statement will execute after the foreach loop has completed.